# How to validate data in Hive HQL while import from Source

Tags: hive

Please explain how to put the validation while importing data from Source in Hive table for example in a bulk of data if some data is corrupt which is not suppose to import so how to discard that data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop ETL process and have strategy to discard the corrupt data. Either you can use 3rd party tools like Informatica big data edition, Talend etc or you need to develop your custom code. It is a major effort.